# What did Cameron see in the Painting?

Tags: ferris-buellers-day-off

In *Ferris Bueller's day off* in the museum scene: we see Cameron staring intently at a certain painting, I was wondering what the meaning behind this is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## He sees himself.

John Hughes explained that whilst looking closer at this painting Cameron keeps seeing less and less of the child, he also thinks that the child ***is*** him, and if you looked close at him (Cameron) you would see nothing. Here's the video where he explains this.

Comment: Your explanation stays quite...cryptic really. I have a hard time making out what you're trying to say here. Can you elaborate a little more what you mean with this, especially in a way that doesn't have us rely on an ephemeral YouTube commentary too much?

Comment: @NapoleonWilson i hope this edit clarified (at least a little) i'm sorry not quite sure where my sense of organization was whilst writing this :/